# desaparece el resultado del button java

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo **HTML** y `JavaScript`. Tengo un problema cuando quiero mostrar el resultado al presionar un botón, ya que se muestra pero a los segundos desaparece.

```js
function Num_Pares(){
    //var aNum = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
    var aNum = ["2", "4", "6", "8", "10"];
    document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = aNum;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="Num_Pares()">PARES</button>
  <p id="par"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es debido a que estas usando un `button` dentro de una etiqueta `form` por lo cual de manera predeterminada el `browser` lo toma como si fuera un `submit` es decir como si estuvieras enviando los datos de formulario, para solucionar esto basta con cambiar la etiqueta `form` por un `div` o podrías añadirle a la etiqueta `button` la propiedad `type` con valor `button`, así:

```js
function Num_Pares(){
    //var aNum = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
    var aNum = ["2", "4", "6", "8", "10"];
    document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = aNum;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="Num_Pares()">PARES</button>
    <p id="par"></p>
</form>
```